# Google Apps Script - JDBC Connection Failed

Tags: javascript, mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, connection-string

I am attempting to open a connection from a Google Apps Spreadsheet without success, using example code from the Google Apps Developers reference (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc)

```
function insert() {
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "a", "a");
```

ERROR: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. (line 56)

I have tried replacing "localhost" with my specific IP address.

I am able to connect successfully to my database using Access, ODBC and the above credentials so I know it's a JDBC / Google-apps-script issue.

CLASSPATH points to the correct jar file as shown by:

```
C:\>echo %CLASSPATH%
.;C:\Program Files\Java\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-
bin.jar
```

I am not sure if I have to do anything else, either within my script or google-doc-spreadsheet, or within Windows to set things up correctly.

I understand from one thing I read, that it is not necessary to install the JDBC driver as such but I would appreciate confirmation of same.

I have spent a long time searching the internet for solutions but to no avail.

I am having trouble diagnosing where the problem lies and would greatly appreciate any thoughts anyone may have in that regard.

Comment: Do you use a Public IP or an internal IP to point to your mysql database? Your database must be over a public IP so that Google Servers can reach to your database and execute the query.

Comment: Is there any way to test using localhost?  If not, can anyone give me details of a server in the cloud that I could test with?

Comment: If you Google for "free mySQL database", you will find a lot of listings. Erlier I tried with http://www.freemysql.net/ and it worked perfect.

Comment: Are you able to provide the connection string that you tried?

Comment: Please check my comment in the answer, and update by megabyte1024.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `localhost` is used as the host. Google Apps Scripts are executed on Google servers and not on local computers. This means that the scripts cannot access the `localhost` and the error is logical.

To get rid of the error is necessary to have an SQL Server accessible outside of a local network (public in internet). It can be a MySQL port forwarded behind of a firewall or a 3rd part public SQL service.

[Searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=MySQL%20public) in internet, I found a few public MySQL Servers, but I don not know either they are online or not ([link #1](http://cgd.jax.org/cgdsnpdb/utils/public_mysql.php), [link #2](http://cgd.jax.org/cgdsnpdb/utils/public_mysql.php), [link #3](http://www.ensembl.org/info/data/mysql.html))

**Update 00**: The JDBC Service has a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1856) with impossibility to resolve host name to IP. I tried to test using the following code. It makes a connection to the DB.

```
function test() {
  var connection = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://193.62.203.76:3306/", "anonymous", "");
  debugger;
}
```

Comment: The following does not work so I'm still left unsure whether there is something wrong with my setup or if (like you say) the particular server is not currently running.  Any ideas?  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:cgd-dev.jax.org", "pup", "puppass");

Comment: Hi Gram, Same code earlier run fine for me. But now it is not working. I tried it it 1 year ago.  Connection string which I used is conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://free-mysql.BizHostNet.com:3306/1309072706", "1309072706", "mySecret");

Comment: Thank-you @Waqar-Ahmed and @megabyte1024.  I was able to confirm the connection by listing the databases on the server you gave.  I used the following code `function test() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://193.62.203.76:3306/", "anonymous", "");
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("show databases");
  var dbList = stmt.executeQuery();
  dbList.next();
  var row = 0;
  Logger.log("Start of Log:");
  while(dbList.next()){
    Logger.log(dbList.getString(1));
    row++;
  }
}`    Goto menu item, View-->Logs to see the results.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE FOR READERS OF THIS POST: It is NOT necessary to download any JDBC driver software to your development machine.  Nor is it necessary to set the CLASSPATH Windows Environment variable, as I had thought when I first posted my question above.  The reason is that (as megabyte1024 pointed out) Google-Apps-Scripts run in the cloud and NOT on the local machine.  I had not appreciated this fact when I made my initial post.