# Google App Script - MySql 8 - JDBC Connection Failed

Tags: ssl, jdbc, google-apps-script, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a self-hosted MySql 8 instance from a Google AdWords Script (effectively an App Script) using the `Jdbc` utility over SSL. My code follows the specifications in these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528221/how-to-connect-to-database-with-ssl-in-google-apps-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151909/google-apps-script-jdbc-connection-failed).

No matter what I do, I still get the following error:
`ERROR: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out that the `Jdbc` utility only works with versions of MySql up to `5.7`.

I thought I would post this here posthumously in case I can save someone else time.

Comment: I've been looking for a clue like this all day long. It a shame that in Google App Script tuto we don't have that information: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#creating_other_database_connections

Answer (score 3):

The [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119660771) has been raised [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119660771) and marked as fixed recently.

Other related issues can be searched [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%20status:open%20mysql%20)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like Google has updated the jdbc connector. It is working for me now,

Comment: It does not work for me. I have Cloud SQL MySQL 8.0, and I used the exact tutorial of GCP (link at the end), and it still gave me the connection error. MySQL 8.0 also not compatible to Data Studio. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#create_a_database_user_and_table