# Google Apps Script shows: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/database_name', 'username', 'password');
```

I tried to connect with this code in google apps script but it shows "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."
The username and password are correct and the user can be accessed from anywhere. I am sure there is remote access because I can establish the connection with "get data from mySQL database" in MS Excel. The port in server firewall is also open for everyone. The connection still failed. 
My mySQL version is 8.0.15, should I use a different code to establish the connection? Or what might my problem be?

Comment: Welcome. Bad news, I'm afraid. [Google App Script - MySql 8 - JDBC Connection Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105800/) advises that the Jdbc utility only works with versions of MySql up to 5.7.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you so much for your reply. But is there a way to connect mySQL 8.0 to google sheets with or without google apps script? What I do now is export my database everyday as csv on my server and import in to google sheets. It's frustrated because I have to manually export it every few hours

Comment: I know this will sound silly but... do you have access to _ANY_ MYSQL5 database/server. It would be good to confirm that the syntax in your code is not contributing to the failure. BTW, did you [whitelist the IP addresses as required](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#creating_other_database_connections)

Comment: @Tedinoz I did whitelist them. Anyway thanks for your help.