# Connection problem after migrato to MySQL8

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, database-connection

I migrated a database from MySQL 5 to MySQL 8 and I updated the connection parameters in the scripts I use in my Google spreadsheet:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X:3306/DB_NAME?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8', 'MY_USER', 'MY_PW');
```

When I run, I get a generic connection error:

> A connection to the database could not be established. Check the connection string, user name and password

All parameters are correct and work with other tool.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Script - MySql 8 - JDBC Connection Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105800/google-app-script-mysql-8-jdbc-connection-failed)