# Error connecting to SQL Server database on Google Cloud SQL from Google Apps Script:

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2017 database on Google Cloud SQL through Google Apps Script using Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection.  I can connect successfully to the database using SQL Server Management Studio.

- Connection to this instance is configured for Public IP without requiring SSL
- I have whitelisted  IP addresses as instructed in [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)
- Relevant connection code from Apps Script function is listed below

```
7  var connectionName = '<instance connection name>';
8  var user = '<user>';
9  var userPwd = '<password>';
10 var db = '<database name>';
11
12 function readFromTable_getCloudSqlConnection() {
13  
14  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName + '/' + db;
15  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
16
17  var start = new Date();
18  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
19  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
20  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM peeps');
```

Error in the Apps Script logs is:

> *Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.
>       at readFromTable_getCloudSqlConnection(Code:15:19)*

Error in the SQL Server logs from the Google Cloud SQL logs

> *Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 148.*

and

> *Login failed for user 'a-280598101372-\a-280598101372-$'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Login lacks connect endpoint permission. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]
>   "*

It seems to be a permission issue on the SQL Server database. I tried searching for that SQL Server error message, and most posts reference granting proper permissions to users and/or roles, which I don't believe the users created through Cloud SQL have or can modify.

Comment: Not familiar with sql server, but you could try creating Login for 'a-280598101372-\a-280598101372-$'  through cloud console?

Comment: Thx @TheMaster for the quick response.  User account created through the cloud console doesn't accept domain\user format.   (backslash not allowed).   Tried creating just with the user a-280598101372-$.  Same behavior.  Able to log in through SSMS with that user, but get the same error message when trying to connect via JDBC from AppsScript

Comment: you could try `getConnection` without cloudsql..

Comment: Thx for the suggestion @TheMaster.  Modified the connection to

`var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://<ip address>:3306/'+ db;
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
`
Same error.  Also tried changing to the standard SQL Server port number 1433.  Still no luck.  :(

Comment: Does sqlserver logs show the same user?

Comment: One last shot in the dark: [switch gcp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) 2. set [iam permissions as described here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/roles-and-permissions)... Also look into cloudsql proxy. I think apps script uses a type of that proxy by default

Comment: Yes, user actually doesn't change in the error logs regardless of which user is used in the connection string.  I switched the project from the default project to the same GCP standard project where the SQL instance is defined.  Also, used IAM permissions to add Cloud SQL Client to my account.  Unfortunately, all same result.  I was able to get mySQL database to work, so abandoning the idea of using SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Try creating a [issue in the issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905).

Comment: Check out this tutorial that goes step-by-step through setting up a connection to CloudSQL. https://youtu.be/VFE0Cbq581c

Comment: Facing the same issue, did anyone got an answer for this.

Comment: @NitinRawat Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105800