# Cannot connect google sheets to Mysql with JDBC

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, google-sheets

I connect googlesheets to a Mysql DB using :

```
function getDBConnection_(data)
{
  data = data || getMySqlConnectionData_();
  // getCloudSqlConnection
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://' + data.host + ':3306/' + data.database + '?characterEncoding=UTF-8', data.username, data.password);  
                             //  dbName?characterEncoding=UTF-8
                             //  jdbc:mysql://yoursqlserver.example.com:3306/database_name
  return conn;  
}
```

I get the error:

> Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. Please try again.

I have not been able to connect for a while using this code when It was working perfectly a while ago. It seems there are now whitelisting needs for google IPs but I do not understand how.
Btw, my server has no whitelisting policy and is open to any connection.

Comment: Did you update your mysql? Your mysql version?

Comment: No, I did not upgrade anything

Comment: @R_life_R are you sure? If you can connect from a remote (and you did not explicitly whitelist that IP), you should be able to connect with the `Jdbc`. Can you tell if there was a configuration change on the side of the server? Did you migrate the script project from Rhino to V8 runtime? Btw, there is also an open issue on the issue tracker that matches your signature: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119660771

Comment: Also this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761643. and this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756432. And this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764908. Could be any of it. Fragmentation of information with the public tracker is horrible :(

Comment: Check this out as well, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105800/google-app-script-mysql-8-jdbc-connection-failed

Comment: Ok i use MySQL > 5.7 (8) so this might be the reason...

Comment: @R_life_R - yeah, probably, sorry that we probably won't be able to help beyond that - please, star one (or all) of the issues on the issue tracker - hopefully Google engineers will look into it. As a workaround, you can move to a cloud function that will connect to the DB for you and perform the operations required (e.g. with a command line), then request that function via `UrlFetchApp` to get the data/trigger an action. That might be a too complex setup to stomach, though