# How to connect to MySQL instance on Google Compute Engine via Apps Script JDBC?

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, google-compute-engine

I've successfully connected to a Google Cloud MySQL instance using GAS and JDBC. As a sanity check, I also connected to a MySQL instance on a [free hosting site](https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/). Despite these successful connections, I can't seem to do this with a MySQL instance on Google Compute Engine using the following command:

`var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://11.111.111.111:3306/myDBName",user,pwd)`,

where `11.111.111.111` is the external IP address that I retrieved from the Google Cloud Platform page for my VM instance.

Note that I've mainly worked with local instances of databases so I might be missing something obvious here. I'm wondering if I don't understand something about how to use the server? Am I supposed to use an IP address other than the external IP provided by Google? Below are the things that I've thought through to try to solve this.

**Establish MySQL user**

Here's how I setup the user in MySQL:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When that didn't work, I tried:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I did double-check that I can login via the command line using the user/pwd credentials.

**MySQL install**

I used [Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/setup-mysql) for how to install MySQL on Compute Engine (Ubuntu).

I double-checked that I'm using MySQL 5.7 since it seems [up to 5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105800/google-app-script-mysql-8-jdbc-connection-failed) is supported by GAS JDBC.

`mysql --version` returns `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.36, for Linux (x86_64)`.

**Port**

I used `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to check the port, and it is 3306. I also enabled port forwarding on my VM instance.

**config file**

In `mysqld.cnf`, I changed
`bind-address            = 127.0.0.1` to `bind-address            = 0.0.0.0`. There was no line for `skip-networking` to comment out. After making edits, I restarted the service using `sudo systemctl restart mysql`.

**IP addresses**

When I look in the firewall section for my VM, I only see two filtered IP addresses: `10.128.0.0/9` and `0.0.0.0/0`.

Also, I tried `sudo ufw allow 3306`, which didn't help me connect either.

I know that Google says to [whitelist IP addresses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) but the instructions that they give for external databases are actually for Cloud SQL. I'm not sure what to do with that info or if it's necessary since I was able to connect to other databases all under the same Google account.